# No data-id attribute exists for Kendo grid row

Tags: jquery, html, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid, set up as shown below, with the field ASPNetUserName specified as the model id.  I was expecting for the generated rows to contain a "data-id" attribute, which would allow me to select the desired row.  Unfortunately, the only html generated for each grid row is "`<tr class="k-alt">`", so I have no way of selecting the desired row.

I was expecting the output for each row in the grid to be like `<tr data-id="joeUser">data here</tr>`

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Analytics.Web.Models.UserModel>() 
      .Name("InternalUserGrid")
      .DataSource(ds => 
          ds.Server()
          .Model(m => m.Id(i => i.UserName))
          .Destroy(d => d.Action("Delete", "InternalUser"))
          .Update(u => u.Action("Edit", "InternalUser"))
          .Create(c => c.Action("Create", "InternalUser"))
          )
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes(new {id = "createButton"}))   
      .BindTo(Model)
      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(u => u.UserName).Width(250);
              columns.Command(c => { c.Destroy();c.Edit();} );
          })
      .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
      .Resizable(r=> r.Columns(true))
      .Selectable()
      .Scrollable())
```

Comment: So your using Username for the Id field as well as your 1 column right? If it's showing up in the column you should have access to it. Are you trying to get the Id in JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your grid selection like this

`.Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))`

And then

```
 $('#Grid').click(function () {
    var gview = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
    var Guid = selectedItem.UserName;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that .Selectable lambda, but I'm still not getting a data-id attribute on my tr tag... What I'm wanting to do is be able to select a SPECIFIC row, not just the currently selected row. Here's a fiddle that creates rows with the data-id attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/rusev/ZpCAy/3/ . As long as the model..id value exists, it generates that data-id attribute.  My lambda - m => m.Id(i => i.UserName) should do the same thing, but doesn't.

Comment: why do you need the data-id attribute to select a row. Why not just find the selected row based off of Order ID

Comment: That's my problem - there's no way to find a specific row - the row has no attributes to query on, just <tr class="k-alt"> - The fiddle works and is easily queryable... My Razor code which should do the same thing creates html that is unqueryable.